How to pass an anonymous function to labeller argument in ggplot's facet_wrap() to add text to the existing labels?
How can I paste an additional constant text to ggplot facet labels?
For example, I have this current plot:
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(120, c(0, 2, 4)),
  y = rnorm(120, c(1, 2, 1)),
  z = letters[1:3]
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~z)


Created on 2024-05-05 with reprex v2.0.2
Now let's say that I want to add the same prefix (Foo = ) string to all facet labels:

If I do
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~z, labeller = \(x) paste("foo = ", x))

I get:

How can I tweak the function I pass to labeller to show foo = [preexisting label] ?

This is almost exactly the example provided in the on line documentation.  Or, for instance, here.

you're right, thanks! But for this I had to look in as_labeller() help page, which is a function I didn't consider to begin with.

You have to wrap your function inside labeller() like so:
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(120, c(0, 2, 4)),
  y = rnorm(120, c(1, 2, 1)),
  z = letters[1:3]
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~z,
    labeller = labeller(z = \(x) paste("foo = ", x))
  )


